# List Group and SubGroup

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following class

```
class Country
{
   int CtryID {get; set;}
   List<City> city {get; set;}
}

class City
{
   string county {get; set;}    
   int sqkm {get; set;}
}
```

The CtryID has values like 1,2,3 and county has values like "County 1" , "County 2" and so on

I want a result like this

```
1
   County 1
   County 6
   County 3
2   
   County 9
   County 4
   County 2
```

How can I achieve this using a Lambda query?

This is what i have used. The list is called ListA

```
 var lst = from aa in ListA
                    from cny in aa.ctryid
                    select new
                    {
                        CountryID= aa.CtryID,
                        CountyName= cny.County
                    };
```

Query 2: Also in my second query (seperate from first one) I want to orderby the Country and then each City inside the Country, *without repeating* the Country multiple times for each City?

Comment: ? That was just expected result. I am asking how to achieve it using a LINQ query

Comment: I'll explain: assuming you have a `List<Country>` - each Country has a `List<City>`. If you iterate over the Countries and print them one by one, you get the output you want. You don't need a query or to manipulate the data - you already store the data the way you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I get. When I print, The CtryID is printed for each county..that's not what is needed as clear in my expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var countryGroups = (from aa in ListA
                    from cny in aa.ctryid
                    select new
                    {
                        CountryID= aa.CtryID,
                        CountyName= cny.County
                    }).GroupBy(n => n.CountryID);
```

This will group your results by `CountryID`, but the output won't be a list -- it will be the groupings.

To output, iterate over the `countryGroups`, and in each of those iterate over the `CountyName` objects.